# Login Form|| Potential Bug || 2.9.0

Tags: login

So I'm using this code to have users login from the front-end:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            {if logged_out}
            {exp:member:login_form class="login" id="login_form" return="/login"}           
            <input type="hidden" name="auto_login" value="1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label><br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            {/exp:member:login_form}
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p><a href="{site_url}{admin_path}.php?S=0&D=cp&C=login&M=forgotten_password_form">Forgot Password?</a></p>
            {/if}

            {if logged_in}
            <h2>You Are logged in as {screen_name}</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{site_url}{admin_path}.php" target="_blank">Control Panel</a></li>
                <li><a href="{site_url}{admin_path}.php?/cp/content_publish/entry_form&channel_id=3&entry_id=7" class="cp" target="_blank">Edit Global Elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="{site_url}">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="{path='logout'}">Logout</a></li>
            {/if}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm not actually getting logged in. So it's like the `{if logged_in}{/if}` isn't actually working.

I'm using that same code in older builds so it must be a bug right? :) My settings for "Control Panel Session Type" and "Website Session Type" are set to COOKIES ONLY.

I'm also using the same `.htaccess` I've always used as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a good ole `htaccess` issue.

I was mistakenly rewriting the URL (only needs to be done on LIVE, not DEV) when it's launched and since this is on a DEV environment I commented this out:

```
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# </IfModule>
```

Wa-laaa!

Comment: Kevin at EL said it was in fact a bug and you can read about it here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20520/simple-search-bug-grid-fields htaccess also helped but I've tested that you in fact do not need to altar that depending on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it with *ExpressionEngine v2.9.0 - Build Date: 20140715*, with "Control Panel Session Type" and "Website Session Type" are set to COOKIES ONLY.

Works as expected for me. So check if you really not login. Can be that you was not login in CP, but on site.

Comment: Did you try it with the code that I had on a login template? Those conditionals don't appear to be working properly for me.

Comment: yes, I use your code. Plus change parameters as in your description.

Comment: So you have a login template in use? Can I see your code? Perhaps I missed something. But I'm using {if logged_in}SHOW STUFF{/if} but when I revisit the CP EE wants me to re-login.

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by "Can be that you was not login in CP, but on site." Isn't that the same thing?